# To count how many cells are striped in a column

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, data-mining, data-processing

```
aw_data = {'first_name': ['Jason', 'Molly', 'Tina', 'Jake', 'Amy'], 
        'last_name': [" 'Miller' "," 'Jacobson' ", 'Ali', 'Milner', 'Cooze'], 
        'age': [42, 52, 36, 24, 73], 
        'preTestScore': [4, 24, 31, 2, 3],
        'postTestScore': [25, 94, 57, 62, 70]}
df = pd.DataFrame(raw_data, columns = ['first_name', 'last_name', 'age', 'preTestScore', 'postTestScore'])
df
```

My task is to first remove the quotes in the last name column and also count how many cells in that column were stripped in the process.

My work:
I am able to strip the quotes in the last name column but how can I count it.
I am using:

```
df["last_name"]=df["last_name"].apply(lambda x: x.replace("'",""))
```

My output should be 'two'.
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: `df['last_name'].str.contains("'").sum()` ?

Comment: @anky this will also count names that have `'` in them (but so is OP's `.replace`). This might be a problem or not. Can use `str.extract`

Comment: You can use str.count, df["last_name"].str.count("'")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> count how many cells in that column were stripped in the process

You can use:

```
df['last_name'].str.split("'").str[1:-1].str.len().ne(0).sum()
```

To see the difference between my comment and this ,consider this example:

```
raw_data = {'first_name': ['Jason', 'Molly', 'Tina', 'Jake', 'Amy'], 
    'last_name': [" 'Miller's' "," 'Jacobson's' ", 'Ali', 'Milner', "Cooze's"], 
    'age': [42, 52, 36, 24, 73], 
    'preTestScore': [4, 24, 31, 2, 3],
    'postTestScore': [25, 94, 57, 62, 70]}
df = pd.DataFrame(raw_data, columns = 
    ['first_name', 'last_name', 'age', 'preTestScore', 'postTestScore'])
print(df)

  first_name       last_name  age  preTestScore  postTestScore
0      Jason     'Miller's'    42             4             25
1      Molly   'Jacobson's'    52            24             94
2       Tina             Ali   36            31             57
3       Jake          Milner   24             2             62
4        Amy         Cooze's   73             3             70
```

You can use:

```
df['last_name'].str.split("'").str[1:-1].str.len().ne(0).sum()
#2 since the last_name `Cooze's` contains an apostrophe but not quoted.
```

Whereas:

```
df['last_name'].str.contains("'").sum()
#3 since it counts all rows having an apostrophe
```

Answer (score 2):

You may try `str.findall` and `sum`

```
In [99]: df.last_name.str.findall(r"^ *\'|\' *$").astype(bool).sum()
Out[99]: 2
```

---

On modified sample df:

```
  first_name        last_name  age  preTestScore  postTestScore
0      Jason        'Miller'    42             4             25
1      Molly       Jacobson'    52            24             94
2       Tina             Ali'   36            31             57
3       Jake         Milner's   24             2             62
4        Amy  Cooze             73             3             70

In [106]: df.last_name.str.findall(r"^ *\'|\' *$").astype(bool).sum()
Out[106]: 3
```

Comment: seems like we had similar ideas though a little different, can I borough the astype bool? :P

Comment: @anky: Sure, brother :))

Comment: I guess thats okay, good use of bool, i should have used it instead of checking len()!=0

Answer (score 1):

You can try the below -

```
df[df["last_name"].str.contains("'")].count()["last_name"]
```